# Is there a way to interact with Siri Answers?

Tags: ios, siri

By default, Siri often "answers" questions by producing a result from (amongst others) [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com). Often these results leave me wanting to drill down further to expand on parts of the answer provided, but I can find no way to use the answer to allow me to link from it to more complete information elsewhere on the web.

[image]

Is there a way to jump from such answers to additional sources of information such as Wikipedia or Google? Is there a way to link from the "Alpha" results page that I'm just not seeing?  I'm aware that I can just search Wikipedia or Google from the start; my question is whether the "Alpha" results are a *dead end*.

Comment: Oh, good one, and nice screenshot stitching - can I ask how you did that?

Comment: @stuffe: Photoshop.

Comment: Ah, not some clever stitching app then?  Oh well :)

Comment: @stuffe: Better than a really long iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid so, since they are just a result of your command. The outcome isn't like a webpage where you can click on and on to obtain more information.

But you can still Google or Wikipedia as library in combination with Siri. Whenever you start your command with 'Wikipedia', Siri will search your local Wikipedia for the command you've just said.

For example, if you give Siri the command `Wikipedia Stack Exchange` Siri will search Wikipedia with the Stack Exchange search term:

[image][image]

Same goes for Google. Just add `Google` in front of your command, and you're good to go!

[image][image]

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested in whether the "Alpha" results are a dead end.

Comment: I'm afraid so, since they are just a result of your command. The outcome isn't like a webpage where you can click on and on to obtain more information.

Comment: @Michael: Lead with that and this will be the answer.

Comment: Ok, I've added the answer.